# List grid e list view com bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, listview, bootstrap-4, thumbnail

Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer esse [efeito](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/List-View-Grid-View-Switcher-Plugin-jQuery-simple-list-grid/) que clica no icone acima e a thumbnail troca de modo lista para mogo grid com o bootstrap 4 estou preocurando na internet algum exemplo pronto mais só acho do bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Grid default do Bootstrap 4 é em `Flex`, então vc pode alternar entre `row` e `column` usando as classes nativas do BS4 e mais poucas linhas de CSS.

Como o jQuery tb é padrão do BS4 usei ele mesmo para fazer um `toggleClass` adicionando e removendo a classe `flex-column` (classe original do BS4) e alternar entre `row` e `column`, mas tb precisei setar `flex:1` para o grid ficar ajustado e responsivo sem problemas. *(na verdade esse é o único estilo que vc precisa, o resto do CSS só fiz pra vc poder visualizar melhor o grid)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    div[class^="col"] {
        height: 50px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid green;
        flex: 1;
    }
.coluna {
    flex-direction: column;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>coluna/linha</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="colunaX" class="row flex-column">
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            1 of 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            2 of 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            2 of 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            2 of 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            2 of 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            2 of 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#colunaX").toggleClass("flex-column");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo agora no caso eu precisava estilizar esses conteudos pensei em usar os cards sera que rola ?

Comment: @Kirito Deve rolar, acredito que colocando o card dentro do grid `<div class="col-xs-2">` vai funcionar. Talvez precise de um ajuste ou outro de CSS, mas se agarrar é só postar outra pergunta que te ajudo com isso.

Comment: vou abrir um tópico porque com card não está funcionando

Comment: abri um tópico https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301229/problemas-com-thumbnails-em-modo-lista-e-grid-com-bootstrap