# Problemas com thumbnails em modo lista e grid com bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, thumbnail

preciso fazer com que esses cards fiquem em modo lista e modo grid estou utilizando flex-column para deixar os grids dinâmicos mais quando adiciono os cards eles não funcionam mais esse é o modo lista do meu layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e esse um esboço do modo grid:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue meu código:

```js
$(".button-thumb").click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "grid") {
    $("#list-grid").addClass("flex-column");
    $('#list').addClass('active');
    $('#grid').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $("#list-grid").removeClass("flex-column");
    $('#grid').addClass('active');
    $('#list').removeClass('active');
  }

});
```

```css
background-color: $light-gray;
padding: 15px;
.active {
  color: $orange;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  color: $gray;
  @include transition(all, .2s);
  &:hover {
    color: $orange;
  }
}

label {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: $gray;
}

select {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: $gray;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
    <div class="box-lists">
      <button id="list" class="button-thumb active" value="list"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></button>
      <button id="grid" class="button-thumb" value="grid"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></button>
      <label for="select"> | Ordenar por:</label>
      <select id="select">
        <option value="">Mais Próximo</option>
        <option value="">Mais Distante</option>
        <option value="">Mais visitados</option>
        <option value="">Mais avaliados</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="list-grid" class="row flex-column">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

no caso precisava que meus cards ficassem igual os da primeira imagem mais quando clicasse no botão de mogo grid eles ficassem igual o da segunda imagem.

Comment: Jovem coloca ai o CSS tb, pq o script não funciona sem ele. vlw

Comment: @hugocsl Adicionei o css so que usei SCSS ai não compilou mais da para visualizar ele no editor é o unico css que eu fiz

Answer (score 1):

Confere:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 40%; // Alterar para 50% para tela cheia.
    padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<button onclick="listView()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Lista</button> 
<button onclick="gridView()"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</button> 

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Coluna 1</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Coluna 2</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Coluna 3</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Coluna 4</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

var i;

function listView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "100%";
  }
}

function gridView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "50%"; // Alterar para 50% para tela cheia.
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

var i;

function listView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "100%";
  }
}

function gridView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "40%"; // Alterar para 50% para tela cheia.
  }
}
```

```css
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button onclick="listView()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Lista</button> 
<button onclick="gridView()"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</button> 

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Coluna 1</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Coluna 2</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Coluna 3</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Coluna 4</h2>
    <p>Conteúdo 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note que formatei as divs com o uso de CSS, usei 40% no width pois aqui no executar exemplo não estava mostrando em grid, mas você pode adaptá-la para o seu layout, totalmente responsivo. Dentro da DIV com o conteúdo, você insere o formato segundo seu layout, com duas colunas, a primeira com "width 100%" quando a div recebe o valor do css .column e remove o valor de "width" quando a div tem o valor css ,column removido.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

Vamos manter as coisas simples :)

Refiz o exemplo usando minha outra resposta e colocando o `Card` dentro. Repare que a única coisa que eu precisei fazer foi ajustar a largura da coluna com a classe default `col-8` e ***quando o grid estiver em lista*** eu coloco o `card` com `flex-direction: row`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    div[class^="col"] {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid green;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .coluna {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .flex-column div > .card{
        flex-direction: row;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <button>coluna/linha</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="colunaX" class="row flex-column">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#colunaX").toggleClass("flex-column");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Jovem basicamente vc resolve com esse css quando o seu grid estiver em forma de lista. não testei pq não teno o compilado SCSS. OBS, coloquei um `offset` aqui para alinhar na direita como está no layout `col-md-8 offset-md-4`

```
.card {
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
.card {
    flex-direction: row;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <div class="box-lists">
            <button id="list" class="button-thumb active" value="list"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></button>
            <button id="grid" class="button-thumb" value="grid"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></button>
            <label for="select"> | Ordenar por:</label>
            <select id="select">
                <option value="">Mais Próximo</option>
                <option value="">Mais Distante</option>
                <option value="">Mais visitados</option>
                <option value="">Mais avaliados</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
        <div id="list-grid" class="row flex-column">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(".button-thumb").click(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "grid"){
          $("#list-grid").addClass("flex-column");
          $('#list').addClass('active');
          $('#grid').removeClass('active');
        }else{
          $("#list-grid").removeClass("flex-column");
          $('#grid').addClass('active');
          $('#list').removeClass('active');
        }
        
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: entendi resolveu aqui, porem quando eu clico no botão que seria para colocar em modo grid eles simplesmente não ficam eles ficam somente em modo lista quando você fez o exemplo naquele primeiro tópico funcionou tranquilo porque só tinha texto agora que crieis os cards ele não quer funcionar

Comment: Não funcionou totalmente, mas a lógica está correta, o que provavelmente não responde aqui no "Executar" deve ser por não estar carregando os links externos de script e css, mas no console nada acusa, mas é isso mesmo, eu optaria por usar boas práticas de css para fazer este recurso funcionar, pois reduz o tempo de produção e o de código.

Comment: então se você remover os cards que eu fiz e adicionar apenas texto pode testar ai você vai ver que funciona tranquilo o problema e que quando adiciono os cards ele não funciona

Comment: @Kirito fiz um Edit na minha resposta olha lá. Eu preferi começar a partir da outra resposta pra simplificar as coisas. Veja que funciona normalmente com o card dentro.